# confusion about vector field notation in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am new to differential geometry and I'm using some notes I found online. Unfortunately I am a bit confused about the notation.
Let $G$ be a lie group and let $X$ be a vector field. Then $X(g)\in T_gG$ is a tangent vector of $G$ at $g$. So far I understand the notation. But now let $\xi\in T_eG$, where $e\in G$ is the identity. In the notes, I find expressions like:
\begin{align}
X_\xi(e)=\xi
\end{align}
Does anyone know what that subscript $\xi$ on a vector field stands for?

Comment: I suspect it should be something like $X_{\xi}(e) = \xi$ (instead of $e$), and that $X_{\xi}$ is a vector field on $G$ built out of the value $\xi\in T_eG$ (for instance, a left invariant vector field). But without more context, it's hard to tell

Comment: yes you're right I edited it. Yes this equation is in the context of left invariant vector field. A left invariant vector field is already defined by its value on the identity, which in this case is $\xi$. So you think the subscript is just to keep track of this value?

Comment: Yes, there is a bijective correspondence $\xi \mapsto X_{\xi}$ between $T_eG$ and left ivariant vector fields, and this is just a way to keep track of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bijective correspondence between tangent vectors at the identity and left invariant vector fields, given by the evaluation at $e$.
The subscript $X_{\xi}$ is meant to keep track of this correspondence.